# fastAPI returns 404 error when I try app.mount

Tags: python, fastapi

when I use below source

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

answer = "APPLE"

@app.get("/answer")
def get_answer():
  return answer

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static", html=True), name="static")
```

then I can get API response "APPLE" but in "/" path, my html page is not found (404 error)
So when I use below source

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

answer = "APPLE"

@app.get("/answer")
def get_answer():
  return answer

app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="static", html=True), name="static")
```

then I can get my page but not api response.

my path is like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Kqh.png)

1. port change
2. port shut down and reload
3. move js file to static folder

Comment: is **main.py** inside **static** folder?

Comment: @deadshot no main.py file is inside root folder and  there is html, js, css etc is inside static folder! should I move main.py file in static folder?

Comment: it’s because you don’t have `localhost:8000/` route. You have `localhost:8000/answer` only. If you want to get APPLE on `localhost:8000/`, change `@app.get("/answer”)` to `@app.get("/“)`

Comment: @ArtemStrogin ah, I don't want to get an answer from root path, but I want to open an HTML file, what should I do?

Comment: What I want to do is when I access "/", the index.html file opens and when I fetch "/answer" from the js on that page, I want to get the answer as the return value. 

Comment: you need to create a function for `@app.get("/“)` that will render template (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/)

Comment: In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804), please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804) as well.