# Fastapi response returning 422 - Error: Unprocessable Entity, wrong model picked for validation

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic, http-status-code-422, missing-template

I am building a custom project using fastapi. I am using pydantic models for defining inputs to the api. The data is stored in MongoDB.

I am getting 422 response code: Unprocessable Entity for a PUT api.
I have not missed any values and moreover the fields mentioned are not present in the model defined.

Below are the models in my app -

```
class AttributeUpdateSpecific(BaseModel):
    scriptname: str
    attribute: str = Field(default="THREADS", description="Accepted values - THREADS, INPUT_FILE, THROUGHPUT, DURATION, JMX")
    value: str

class UpdateAttributeMultiple(BaseModel):
    update: list[AttributeUpdateSpecific]

class Script(BaseModel):
    environment: str
    component: str
    scriptname: str
    scriptdesc: str
    group: list[str]
    scriptstatus: str = Field(default="DONE")
    runid: int
    jmx: str
    variables: dict = Field(default=defaultvariables)
```

Route:

```
@script_router.put("/attributes")
async def update_individual_attributes(records: UpdateAttributeMultiple, test_db: str = Header(default=None)):
    updatecount = 0
    records = records.model_dump()["update"]

    if not test_db:
        raise ex.empty_header_exception()
    
    async for record in records:
        if record["attribute"] not in ["THREADS", "DURATION", "THROUGHPUT", "INPUT_FILE", "JMX"]:
            raise ex.invalid_option_exception()
        try:
            updatecount += await sch.script_update_attribute(test_db, record)

            return {
                "status": "success",
                "description": str(updatecount) + " record(s) updated."
            }
        
        except ValueError:
            raise ex.value_exception()
        except Exception as exception:
            raise ex.internal_server_exception(exception)
```

Request:

```
curl -X 'PUT' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/scripts/attributes' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'test-db: pcm_hpt_master' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "update": [
    {
      "scriptname": "HL_TESTSCRIPT_CO_TEST",
      "attribute": "THREADS",
      "value": "150"
    }
  ]
}'
```

422: Unprocessable Entity - Response

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "type": "missing",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "environment"
      ],
      "msg": "Field required",
      "input": {
        "update": [
          {
            "scriptname": "HL_TESTSCRIPT_CO_TEST",
            "attribute": "THREADS",
            "value": "150"
          }
        ]
      },
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing"
    },
    {
      "type": "missing",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "component"
      ],
      "msg": "Field required",
      "input": {
        "update": [
          {
            "scriptname": "HL_TESTSCRIPT_CO_TEST",
            "attribute": "THREADS",
            "value": "150"
          }
        ]
      },
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing"
    },
    {
      "type": "missing",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "scriptdesc"
      ],
      "msg": "Field required",
      "input": {
        "update": [
          {
            "scriptname": "HL_TESTSCRIPT_CO_TEST",
            "attribute": "THREADS",
            "value": "150"
          }
        ]
      },
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing"
    },
    {
      "type": "missing",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "group"
      ],
      "msg": "Field required",
      "input": {
        "update": [
          {
            "scriptname": "HL_TESTSCRIPT_CO_TEST",
            "attribute": "THREADS",
            "value": "150"
          }
        ]
      },
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing"
    },
    {
      "type": "missing",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "runid"
      ],
      "msg": "Field required",
      "input": {
        "update": [
          {
            "scriptname": "HL_TESTSCRIPT_CO_TEST",
            "attribute": "THREADS",
            "value": "150"
          }
        ]
      },
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing"
    },
    {
      "type": "missing",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "jmx"
      ],
      "msg": "Field required",
      "input": {
        "update": [
          {
            "scriptname": "HL_TESTSCRIPT_CO_TEST",
            "attribute": "THREADS",
            "value": "150"
          }
        ]
      },
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

The fields mentioned as missing are not part of the model defined (UpdateAttributeMultiple), but of another model used for a different request - Script. What might be going wrong here?

Comment: I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804)

Comment: .. and to expand on what Chris is saying, you probably have a `/{foo}` endpoint registered which captures the `/attributes` part of your logic. Change the order of when you register the endpoints to get the static `/attributes` endpoint to be invoked instead (or usually better, have them as separate paths).

Comment: In relation to Mats's comment, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804) as well.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh. Currently the issue was indeed due to the order of placement of the request. There was indeed another api above the one mentioned here that was using the model with the fields that were part of the complaint here. Once I changed the order this works fine.