# Changing HX-GET using JavaScript doesn't change the result?

Tags: javascript, html, fastapi, htmx

I'm looking for help with HTMX. I writing a simple FastAPI app with HTMX and Tailwind and MongoDB database.

I have such a form:

```html
<form id="currencyForm" hx-get="/currency_history_check/EUR" hx-target="#result" hx-swap="innerHTML">
  <select name="currency_id" id="currency_id" onchange="updateFormAction()">
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

And this script:

```js
function updateFormAction() {
        var selectedCurrency = document.getElementById("currency_id").value;
        document.getElementById("currencyForm").setAttribute("hx-get", "/currency_history_check/" + selectedCurrency);
    }
```

Even though the link changes, the result still remains the same
[image]
[image]

When I choose a currency from the select, it does change inside the HTML, however it always shows me EUR values as a return nonetheless.

Where do I make the mistake?

Comment: Maybe the server is hardcoded to EUR.

Answer (score 3):

HTMX won't catch up with the attribute change from the JavaScript, you have to call `htmx.process('your selector');` to force HTMX to re-process the element:

```
function updateFormAction() {
    htmx.find('#currencyForm').setAttribute('hx-get', '/blah');
    htmx.process('#currencyForm');
}
```

But in your case, you don't need any of that. HTMX smart enough to add form fields to the request automatically (check Network tab of the Developer Tools in your browser).

So your form could look like this:

```html
<form id="currencyForm" hx-get="/currency_history_check" hx-target="#result" hx-swap="innerHTML">
  <select name="currency_id" id="currency_id">
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

And without any JavaScript HTMX will call `/currency_history_check` adding `currency_id` to the query string (e.g. `/currency_history_check?currency_id=EUR`).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this. Turns out I had set up wrong API endpoints.

My previous one was:

```py
@app.get('/currency_history_check/{currency_id}', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def currency_history_check(currency_id: str):
    currency_id = currency_id.upper()
```

And now I changed it to this:

```py
@app.get('/currency_history_check', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def currency_history_check(currency_id: str = Query(...)):
    currency_id = currency_id.upper()
```

There was something to do with Query and Path parameters

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804) helpful