# How to call a second endpoint in FastAPI with the same path, but with query parameters?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a code which has two endpoints. One is root and the other one is root with query parameters. However, when I call the second endpoint I am unable to get it called. It is always the first endpoint that gets called.
Even if I change the order of endpoints, the second one is still unreachable.

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()

@router.get('/')
def index():
    return 'Call like https://localhost:5000/?uname=xyz&uemail=abc@xyz.com'

@router.get('/')
def index(uname,uemail):
    return ('User Name is :' + uname + 'and User Email is: '+ uemail)
```

I am expecting the second function to be called, when the root path is called with query parameters.

Comment: In such cases, you should use only a single route.

Comment: To add, if you **need** (you probably do not) different routes, use a different path as well. It will be much easier for the users of the API as well for a route to have consistent results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804), the order in which the endpoints are defined **matters**, as endpoints are evaluated in order. Hence, since both endpoints are using `/` root path, only the first one would be called when issuing a request to, for instance, `http://localhost:8000/`.

What you could do is to define the query parameters as Optional (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804) for more details on Optional parameters), and check inside the endpoint whether the user has included those parameters in the request or not, and respond accordingly. Note that for validating email addresses, you could use [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#pydantic-types)'s `EmailStr` type (requires [email-validator](https://github.com/JoshData/python-email-validator) to be installed), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065165/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74067930/17865804).

### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Optional

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def index(username: Optional[str] = None, email: Optional[str] = None):
    if username and email:
        return {'Username': username, 'Email': email}
    else:
        return 'Username and/or email are missing!'
```

Another solution would be to use custom exceptions, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833284/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283272/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804).