# Input should be a valid integer, unable to parse string as an integer, (But actually the variabel is integer)

Tags: python, parsing, fastapi, pydantic

When making a POST request to '/api/contest/problems', I receive a 422 error response (unprocessable entity) as follows:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "type": "int_parsing",
      "loc": [
        "path",
        "contest_id"
      ],
      "msg": "Input should be a valid integer, unable to parse string as an integer",
      "input": "problems",
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/int_parsing"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, it's clear that contest_id is an integer. Here's the endpoint:

```
@router.get("/api/contest/problems",  tags=["Contest Problem"])
def get_all_contest_problems(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    contest_problems = db.query(ContestProblem).all()
    if not contest_problems:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Contest Problems Not Found")
    return {"status" : "ok","data" : contest_problems}
```

To ensure, here's the model:

```
class Contest(Base):
    __tablename__ = "contests" 
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    # some attribute
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=7))
    
class ContestProblem(Base):
    __tablename__ = "contest_problems"
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    contest_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("contests.id"))
    title = Column(String(255))
    # some attribute
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=7))
    back_populates="contest_problems")
```

And here's the SQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `contest_problems` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `contest_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  -- some attribute
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: I don't think that error can come from querying, only when updating the table.

Comment: Where is your route post handler?

Comment: The POST route probably expects an ID in the URL, so it should be something like `/api/contest/problems/123`. If you leave out `/123` it might treat that as an empty string, which isn't a valid integer.

Comment: You have a different route with `/api/contest/<contest_id>` somewhere, and this is the route that actually gets invoked. The route you've included in your question is not the one generating the error and is not being called. You can fix the issue by registering the more specific route first, then the one that uses a specific integer/path match.

Comment: In addition to the link provided above, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74759329/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76528465/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804)

Comment: ohh dear! Thanks for you all, I made a mistake; I actually created an endpoint /api/contest/{contest_id}, which will be confusing for /api/contest/problems. Thank you for your response!
especially thanks to @MatsLindh